# pycharm - why is interpreter not set properly?

Tags: pycharm

I have many versions of python installed on my system and trying to use a particular version. However, i am not getting it to work with correct version.
When i run a program in pycharm, it is running on

```
/usr/bin/python
```

whereas i have set interpreter as

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

What am i missing?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, seems that you tried to run code using a PyCharm configuration (named *small_codes*).

Everytime you create a new PyCharm configuration, you should choose the correct python interpreter.

In order to modify it for *small_codes* configuration you should go:

```
Run --> Edit Configurations --> select small_codes configuration
```

Then,under *Configuration* tab, you will see the option *Python interpreter*. 
Here, you can choose the correct one, that should be the same of the one selected in PyCharm setting.

Finally you can press on *Apply* and then *Ok*.

In this way interpreters are the same.